# How to create SKUS product selection function like pinduoduo with js functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, function

What i want:
[pinduoduo buy selection image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nb7SM.jpg) And
[video how it works](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IK3rdqT7bnwlLjM0hF5Nr-671Z9yeATx/view?usp=sharing)

What i have:
My products structure and skus what i use for selection. I group by attr_id

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "created_at": "2023-07-30T08:47:14.826201Z",
    "updated_at": "2023-07-30T08:47:14.826201Z",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "store_id": 1,
    "category_id": 3,
    "name": "iphone 14",
    "description": "iphone 14",
    "price": 500000,
    "old_price": 567000,
    "attributes": [
        ...
    ],
    "categories": {
        ...
    },
    "skus": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "product_id": 1,
            "price": 600000,
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "attr_id": 2,
                            "attr_name": "color",
                    "sku_id": 1,
                    "value": "",
                    "value_id": 5,
                    "value_name": "red"
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 4,
                            "attr_name": "ROM",
                    "sku_id": 1,
                    "value": "",
                    "value_id": 9,
                    "value_name": "256GB"
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 13,
                            "attr_name": "RAM",
                    "sku_id": 1,
                    "value": "",
                    "value_id": 14,
                    "value_name": "4GB"
                }
            ],
            "stock": 100
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "product_id": 1,
            "price": 587000,
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "attr_id": 2,
                            "attr_name": "color",
                    "sku_id": 2,
                    "value": "",
                    "value_id": 6,
                    "value_name": "gold"
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 4,
                            "attr_name": "ROM",
                    "sku_id": 2,
                    "value": "",
                    "value_id": 9,
                    "value_name": "256GB"
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 13,
                            "attr_name": "RAM",
                    "sku_id": 2,
                    "value": "",
                    "value_id": 14,
                    "value_name": "4GB"
                }
            ],
            "stock": 100
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "product_id": 1,
            "price": 650000,
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "attr_id": 2,
                            "attr_name": "color",
                    "sku_id": 4,
                    "value": "",
                    "value_id": 5,
                    "value_name": "red"
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 4,
                            "attr_name": "ROM",
                    "sku_id": 4,
                    "value": "",
                    "value_id": 11,
                    "value_name": "1TB"
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 13,
                            "attr_name": "RAM",
                    "sku_id": 4,
                    "value": "",
                    "value_id": 15,
                    "value_name": "8GB"
                }
            ],
            "stock": 100
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "product_id": 1,
            "price": 625000,
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "attr_id": 2,
                            "attr_name": "color",
                    "sku_id": 3,
                    "value": "",
                    "value_id": 12,
                    "value_name": "blue"
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 4,
                            "attr_name": "ROM",
                    "sku_id": 3,
                    "value": "",
                    "value_id": 10,
                    "value_name": "512GB"
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 13,
                            "attr_name": "RAM",
                    "sku_id": 3,
                    "value": "",
                    "value_id": 14,
                    "value_name": "4GB"
                }
            ],
            "stock": 100
        }
    ]
}
```

And how it looks:
[image of what i made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xw0U.png).

Do you have any ideas on how to create a feature where clicking on the desired SKUS will display the SKUS options to select?